# ANN: Language detection

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am trying to recreate google's ["Hello Prediction"](https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/hello_world) algorithm to test my network. I got my training samples from the same place.

---

Since I dont expect you to follow the above link, in short about "Hello Prediction":
It is a "hello world" example for Google Prediction API, basically an example of training
ANN with a large training set consisting of strings of text in Spanish, English and French.
By the end of this exercise network should be able to detect each of the 3 languages.

---

Now I am faced with feeding the data into the network.

How do I manipulate variable length strings of text to be fed into a fixed size network input?

I've seen two solutions that consider word order:

1. Make network input large enough to fit the entire sentence. This is most realistic, but wasteful method. I am sure google has come up with a better way.
2. Break sentences into substrings of fixed size (n) characters like so:
   if n = 2, "abcde" becomes ["ab", "bc", "cd", de"].

Have anyone solved this successfully? Is #2 better than #1? Is there a third solution?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know anything about "Hello Prediction", so it's somewhat difficult to follow what's going on here (we shouldn't have to go read up about it, posts should try to be self-contained), but, from what I can see, #1 won't work because it's greatly impractical to get enough data to get trained well enough. #2 sounds like [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) which is commonly used in practice.

Comment: @Dukeling I have updated my question, to reflect your comment, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try some feature extraction? tf_idf is commonly used in NLP and I think you could find some other useful numerical features.